# Problema github pages y el servicio IONOS

Tags: github, github-pages

Estoy intentando vincular el dominio francmirror.es de ionos a mi página:

> francmirror.github.io

Y lo logro conectar, me soló funciona si busco específicamente:

> "https://www.francmirror.es"

¿Qué puedo hacer?

Answer (score 0):

Para vincular el dominio francmirror.es de ionos a su página francmirror.github.io, debería configurar un registro CNAME en su DNS. El registro CNAME apuntaría a su dirección de GitHub Pages, que es francmirror.github.io.

En el panel de Ionos, debe buscar la opción de configurar DNS y agregar un registro CNAME con el nombre de su dominio (francmirror.es) y la dirección de su repositorio GitHub Pages como valor (francmirror.github.io)

Es importante que el protocolo http y www sean eliminados del dominio en la configuración del CNAME.

Una vez que haya guardado los cambios, puede tardar un tiempo en que los cambios se propaguen a través de la red, pero después de eso debería ser capaz de acceder a su sitio a través de francmirror.es.